# Fragment use is mandatory in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-fragments

As per the Android 4.4 developer guideline we have to use Fragment in each activity. If we make inner fragment class non-static then Android will crash our app when it comes from background to foreground so we need to make the fragment class static. In that case all the variables and classes which have been used in the fragment class (other than fragment class variable) should be static.

I think that will consume more VM memory and the app will be unstable. Can anyone suggest if  I am right? Or suggest if there is other way to overcome that problem.

Here is the snippet of code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Video variable
    MediaRecorder recorder; 
    // Networking variables
    public static String SERVERIP="";
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6775;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
/**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        // User Interface Elements
        VideoView mView;
        TextView connectionStatus;



        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
         NotificationManager notificationManager;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.notifybtnID);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

              // Define UI elements
            mView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_preview);
          //  connectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_status_textview);
            mHolder = mView.getHolder();
           // mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            SERVERIP = "192.168.1.126";
            // Run new thread to handle socket communications
            Thread sendVideo = new Thread(new SendVideoThread());
            sendVideo.start();
        }
public static class SendVideoThread implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            // From Server.java
            try {
                if(SERVERIP!=null){
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                         //   connectionStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                        }
                    });
}
```

Comment: "As per the Android 4.4 developer guide line , We have to use Fragment in each of activity ." -- this is incorrect. You are welcome to use fragments if you wish, or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help , yes you are right i did some mistake in my code that is why my app was not working in Activity but i have correct it now it is working .